# Impossible to change the Culture at runtime with Blazor server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localization, blazor, blazor-server-side

In `startup.cs` :

```
builder.Services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { 
      new CultureInfo("en-US"),
      new CultureInfo("fr") 
};
builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options => {
    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestCulture("en-US");
    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures.ToList();
});
app.UseRequestLocalization();
```

In `MainLayout.razor`, I have 2 buttons to change culture (`'fr'` and `'en-US'`) :

```
public void ChooseLanguage(string myCulture)
{
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(myCulture);
    CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(myCulture);

    var cn = CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName;
    var cv = CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(myCulture));
    var cookie = $"{cn}={cv}";
    JS?.InvokeVoidAsync("eval", $"document.cookie='{cookie}'");
    NAV?.NavigateTo(NAV.Uri,true);
}
```

That's work, a cookie is created in the domain `'localhost'` named `.AspNeCore.Culture` and the content : `c=en-US|uic=en-US` or `c=fr|uic=fr` to me it's correct.

The page is : `Home/Pages/Index.razor` for the ressource I have in root `Resources/Home/Pages/Index.en-US.resx` and `Index.fr.resx` in both files there is an item `Hello`

When I call this page after click on the 2 buttons :

```
@page "/"
@using System.Globalization;
@inject Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.IStringLocalizer<Index> location

<b>CurrentCulture</b>: @CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
<h1>@location["Hello"]</h1>
```

The problems : `@CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` does not display the `CurrentCulture` selected via the buttons of course `@location["Hello"]` does not display the content of the `resx` files but just display `Hello`.

I read this (and few others) : [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=server)

Do you have an idea what's wrong ?

Thanks,

Comment: Try setting `options.SupportedUICultures`

Comment: Thanks, but not work :(

Comment: I think you are missing some essential configuration mentioned on the [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=server#dynamically-set-the-culture-by-user-preference) you have linked yourself in the question, like `Pages/_Host.cshtml` adjustments or the missing call to `app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions)` etc.

Comment: No change, the .AspNetCore.Culture cookie is updated with the culture selected but it's not apply to the UI.

Comment: does this help ? https://www.syncfusion.com/faq/blazor/general/how-do-i-change-languages-in-a-blazor-server-side-application There is a github sample repo linked too.